# Do I a need a DATV for my onward journey while arrive and by depart by air same airline same terminal same day?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, public-transport, transit-visas, loyalty-programs

Hi I am an Indian and have residence permit in NL
I am planning to a book a flight with British Airways from AMS to BOM via LHR
I will have a layover of approx 2 hours in LHR
Arrival and Departure terminal is same (Terminal 5)
Do I still need DATV ?

Comment: Just to be sure, both flights would be on the same ticket, right?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UK check if you need a visa page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no),

> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> (…)
>
> - a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
>   (…)
> - a uniform format category D visa for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland
>   (…)

So if your “residence permit” fits one of the above you don’t need a DATV (not because of the length of the transit but thanks to the permit).

Note that some EU countries deliver permits which are not “uniform format”, I have no idea if that is the case of the NL.